# Mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I know this may sound a simple question and it has been answered several times on stackoverflow but I am a novice and unable to find a working solution from already answered threads. I my gradle I am getting this error:

```
    All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions
26.1.0, 25.3.1, 25.2.0. Examples include `com.android.support:animated-vector
drawable:26.1.0` and `com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1`
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ6qd.png)

The app builds fine and also runs on few devices like API 22 but while testing I figured out that the app crashes on API 19 and few other lower APIs.

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*******"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'    << Error with this line

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Change your target sdk version to 26

Comment: "unable to find a working solution from already answered threads" -- please edit your question to explain in detail what you tried.

Comment: run `gradlew dependencies`, find support libraries with old versions and add it with version 26 to your build.gradle

Comment: could you post the crash report?

Comment: See your Error log dependency version is lower than targeted version

Comment: @Raj changing to 26 didn't work

Comment: Are you have a build tool 26.0.1

Comment: which IDE  u used and this IDE version

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'    26+ replace with 26.0.1

Comment: your build tool version is 26.0.1 but your app compat version is higher 26.1.0 then how it can be work so change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first change your `targetSdkVersion` to 26. You should use same version for android support libraries. You should correct your versions as below:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'  
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
```

As you are not compiling cardView explicitly, there might might be third party library which is using the version 25.3.1. To resolve this compile the below version too:

```
com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0
```

And try to avoid using **+** signs in dependencies, they load bunch of unnecessary versions.